# Problem using AWS S3 with Boto3 for the first time (access denied)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to download some CSV files from a remote repository for an academic course in S3.

They gave me the key and secret key but not the bucket name - they also gave me the files URLs e.g. `rkd.s3.amazonaws.com/file.csv`.

```
class Storage():
"""
Connection to remote S3
"""
    def __init__(self):
        #self.path = path
        self.s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
              aws_access_key_id=my_key_here,
              aws_secret_access_key=my_secret_key_here)
        self.get_buckets()

    def get_buckets(self):
        for bucket in self.s3.buckets.all():
            print(bucket.name)
```

I'm getting:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied.

Comment: The credentials you've been provided do not have suitable IAM permission to enumerate buckets, most likely due to security. Try grabbing `file.csv` directly from the `rkd` bucket & see if you have permission that way.

Comment: how can i grabe a file if a don't have the bucket name? i tried self.s3.download_file('mybucket', 'chapterone.csv', 'file.csv') and i'm getting a botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Comment: `self.s3.download_file('rkd', 'file.csv')` - the bucket name is in the S3 url in your question :)

Comment: this helped me a lot, i wasn't understanding that url at all. thanks :) question is solved!

Comment: you're welcome, have a great weekend

Answer (score 2):

The credentials you've been provided do not have suitable IAM permission to enumerate buckets, most likely due to security.

Try downloading `file.csv` directly from the `rkd` bucket & see if you have permission that way (**rkd**.s3.amazonaws.com/**file.csv**).